# VirtualBox. Как изменить или оставить настоящее имя устройства при пробрасывании его в вирутальную машину?

Tags: администрирование, virtualbox, драйвер, виртуализация, web-камера

При пробрасывании вебкамеры в VirtualBox ей в название добавляется "VirtualBox Webcam"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю через Devices => Webcam

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через Devices => USB => CameraName добавить не получатся, хоть там и есть имя нужной камеры. Ну и сама камера встроена в ноутбук, а не подключена внешне по USB.
Для убирания остальных следов работы в VirtualBox использую VirtualBox Hardened Loader [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/hfiref0x/VBoxHardenedLoader). Но к сожалению на вебкамеру он не влияет.

Как изменить имя камеры - скрыть что она проброшена через VirtualBox?
Ну или как подключить её по USB? - так в название не добавляется "VirtualBox"